# Creating a responsive scatter plot with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, scatter-plot

I am trying to create a venn diagram of two elements from a scatter plot widget on package fl_chart.

```
scatterPlot(screenSize) {
    return ListView(children: [
      SizedBox(
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        child: ScatterChart(
          ScatterChartData(
              scatterSpots:
                  _createSpots(determineCircleLocation(screenSize), screenSize),
              minX: 0,
              minY: 0,
              maxX: screenSize.width,
              maxY: screenSize.height,
              borderData: FlBorderData(show: false),
...
```

I have this problem that whenever I resize my window the scatter circles are moving - so if at a full screen it appeared that they had no intersection, when I resize the screen it appears like it has an intersection.
I was trying to wrap my plot in a SizedBox thinking that would stop the resizing side effects but it didn't.

Here's a demo of the problem

[image: gif]

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

While writing this I thought that by changing `maxX` and `maxY` to be some constants could help, but it resulted even worst outcome.

Answer (score 0):

because we set a direct size (no matter in which size is it running) this problem happens.
You can check the window size, then update the dot's radius based on the window size.
(I calculated a number, then multiplied with radiuses).

Watch the video below. and [check the code here](https://gist.github.com/imaNNeoFighT/d27fbc75521ac5135e829f73d4a84339):

```
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) {
    final size = constraints.biggest.shortestSide;
    final radiusMultiplier = size / 800;
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 18.0),
      child: ScatterChart(
          ScatterChartData(
            scatterSpots: [
              ScatterSpot(5, 7, radius: 60 * radiusMultiplier,),
              ScatterSpot(8, 4, radius: 20 * radiusMultiplier,),
              ScatterSpot(3, 8, radius: 70 * radiusMultiplier),
            ],
            minX: 1,
            maxX: 10,
            minY: 1,
            maxY: 10,
          )
      ),
    );
  },
)
```

[image]